# Create Filter activity in automation with SSJS

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud, ssjs

We would like to create a filter activity and add it on an automation based on Data filter already existing.
Is it possible to create it with SSJS ? I created the Data filter with SSJS but I don't know if it's possible to create the Filter acttivity with SSJS.

Thank you in advance,
Ilyass

I created the Data filter with SSJS.